# StackNavigator - skipping one page the page in the stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

In my React Native application, I have used React Navigation library for implementing navigation. I built the whole application upon `StackNavigator`. Now I ran into a problem where I don't know how to solve. Sometimes based on `some condition`, I want to `skip` one of the pages in my stack navigator.

For example, I have four screens.

```
const GuidelinesNavigation = StackNavigator({
  'ScreenOneRoute': { screen: ScreenOne },
  'ScreenTwoRoute': { screen: ScreenTwo },
  'ScreenThreeRoute': { screen: ScreenThree },
  'ScreenFourRoute': { screen: ScreenFour }
});
```

and I want to skip the `third` screen based on the decision that I make on the `second` screen, and I don't know how to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This looks like a well written question.

Comment: Thanks, I try my best to make it easy to understand so I can get an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate between these pages however you want to, e.g. Suppose you have a button in `ScreenOne`, and on press that button, you want to take user to `ScreenThree`, you can do something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenThree')}>
    <Text>
        Go to Screen 3
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If you have another button that goes to `ScreenTwo`, do exactly the same thing but change 'ScreenThree' to `ScreenTwo`

Comment: The docs are pretty clear https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop

As stated above you can simply hardCode where to navigate too without worrying about stacks and index.

Answer (score 0):

*StackNavigator* provides a way for your app to transition between screens where each new screen is placed on top of a stack.
Each screen in your app will receive a *navigation* prop which should be used in order to navigate to another screen of your app.

You should just add *if* statement with some condition and implement your logic like in the code below. You can find more information by following the [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack).

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            if (someOption) {
              navigate("ScreenThreeRoute");
            } else {
              navigate("ScreenFourRoute");
            }
          }}
          title="Change Screen"
        />
      </View>
     )
   }
}
```